# What if my life gets repeated again and again?

Tags: metaphysics, consciousness, reality, solipsism

What if only I am real? What if when I die my life starts all over again? Like an endless loop? And all of my memories get deleted? Please give me arguments against this!

Comment: It's a time-honored philosophical idea. For all we know it's true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return. Nietzsche had the same idea. Or perhaps he didn't, evidently his remarks are ambiguous as described here.
 https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nietzsche/#EterRecuSame. Even physicists have a speculative idea along those lines. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if my life starts all over again for all eternity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89417/what-if-my-life-starts-all-over-again-for-all-eternity)